# Hive: Is there a way to get the aggregates of all the numeric columns existing in a table?

Tags: hive, pivot, hql, transpose, aggregates

I have a table containing over 50 columns (both numeric and char), is there a way to get the overall statistics without specifying each column?

As an example:

`a  b  c  d 
 1  2  3  4 
 5  6  7  8 
 9  10 11 12`

Ideally I would have something like:

`column_name  min avg max sum
 a            1   5   9   15 
 b            2   6   10  18 
 c            3   7   11  21 
 d            4   8   12  24`

Nevertheless, getting one aggregate at a time it would be more more than helpful.

Any help/idea would be highly appreciated.

Thank you,
O

Answer (score 0):

You can parse DESCRIBE TABLE output using AWK and generate comma separated string of SUM(col) as sum_col for numeric columns and column_list for all other columns.
In this example it generates select statement with goup by. Run in shell:

```
TABLE_NAME=your_schema.your_table

NUMERIC_COLUMNS=$(hive -S -e "set hive.cli.print.header=false; describe ${TABLE_NAME};" | awk -F " " 'f&&!NF{exit}{f=1}f{ if($2=="int"||$2=="double") printf c "sum("toupper($1)") as sum_"$1}{c=","}')

GROUP_BY_COLUMNS=$(hive -S -e "set hive.cli.print.header=false; describe ${TABLE_NAME};" | awk -F " " 'f&&!NF{exit}{f=1}f{if($2!="int"&&$2!="double") printf c toupper($1)}{c=","}')

SELECT_STATEMENT="select $NUMERIC_COLUMNS $GROUP_BY_COLUMNS from $TABLE_NAME group by $GROUP_BY_COLUMNS"
```

I'm checking only int and double columns. You add more types. Also you can optimize it and execute DESCRIBE only once, then parse result using same AWK scripts. Hope you got the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Still, something is not right with the group by statements, as I need the overall sum. In this case, my final table would contain only 2 columns, *the name of the variable* and *the overall sum*. It seems that the above suggestion does a "group by" the char variables.

Comment: @OanaB  Yes. Remove that part if you do not need and build SELECT_STATEMENT that fits your needs. I provided you with Idea, I'm not to do your task completely of course. Anyway you need to modify. Just remove NUMERIC_COLUMNS

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but for some reason it doesn't recognize my table, it says `cannot recognize input near 'from' 'my_schema' '.' in select clause`
 :( While if I use your code, it runs just fine. PS: I did remove the `$GROUP_BY_COLUMNS` bit before the `from` statement.

Comment: @OanaB It can be with older version of Hive. Older Hive did not work with schema.table in describe. it required: use my_schema; describe table (without schema). So try to add one more SCHEMA variable and remove it from table. and add use $SCHEMA. You can print command passed to hive instead of executing it and try to run manually and fix. Debug it on your Hive. It worked good on mine environment

Comment: I'm still struggling a bit to understand how AWK works, but I'm getting there. Currently using the script you posted, it doesn't recognize the numeric columns: sum(c1): not found [No such file or directory]. I changed the data type to int, but it's still not working. Thanks for your help!