# How to get the list of all columns having NULL values only in hive?

Tags: sql, hive, null, hiveql

I am working on a huge data set having more than 10k rows and more than 600 columns in **Hive**.
There are multiple rows columns which having `NULL` value for all the rows.
How can I get the list of all the columns having only `NULL` values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `count(col)` to count all `NOT NULL` rows for some column.

Columns with all `NULL`s will have `0` counts:

```
select
count(col1) as col1_cnt,
count(col2) as col2_cnt,
...
count(colN) as colN_cnt

from table
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. BUT using above query I will need to write all the column names in the query .As I mentioned the number columns are more than 600. Is there a way to use some dynamic query to check for all the columns in the meta data table ?

Comment: @ManjeetSuman You can use some other tools like shell to parse DESCRIBE command output and build the query. In Hive there is no dynamic query feature

Comment: @ManjeetSuman Example of parsing DESCRIBE and building query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58012261/2700344 You can customize this example to generate required output